# Calculating a limit using Wolfram cloud or otherwise

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, numerics

> Using Wolfram cloud or otherwise, I need to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\ 4^{2n}}{e^{2n}}\ \left\{\binom{2n}{n} d_{2n}a_n\right\}\leq \frac{3}{4}$$ where $$a_n:= -\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj^2(2(H_{n-j}-H_j)\log((j+n)!)    $$where $d_{n}=\text{LCM}(1,2,...,n)$ and  $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$

I tried a code on Wolfram cloud as

```
Limit[4^{2*n}*n*FractionalPart[-2*Sum [Binomial[n,j]^2* LCM@@Range[2*n] *(HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}]]/e^{2*n} , n -> Infinity]
```

And the answer was

```
"This computation has exceeded the time limit for your plan.""
```

Please find the limit or its upper bound. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot use list brackets in the place of parentheses. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720) Correcting this won't help in this case, but you need to be using the proper syntax.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. So according to the answer the limit can be any numner between $-\infty$ and $0$?

Comment: I don't know anything about the limit.

Comment: In the sense of classical analysis, the answer is telling you the limit as the ***real*** variable n approaches infinity does not exist; it is also telling you that the function oscillates between 0 and infinity as n approaches infinity. It is not indicating whether it is an open or a closed interval, but a moment's thought makes it clear that 0 is in the range for $n>N$, for any $N$. Perhaps you meant `DiscreteLimit[]`? It does not evaluate unfortunately...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your comment. So how do we give a rigorous proof in sense of classical analysis that the limit as $n$ approaches infinity does not exist. I would really appreciate if you would write an answer.

Comment: The site for mathematics answers is math.SE.  Hint: Think in terms of the limit of $a(x)$ times the fractional part of $f(x)$, where both $a(x)$ and $f(x)$ increase continuously without bound as $x$ increases without bound. Anyone who wants to deal with `Binomial[2*n, n]` where `n` is a real variable should learn to figure out this limit on their own, imo. (Teach a person to fish and all that.)

Comment: After you’ve gotten an answer, please don’t edit the question in a way that invalidates that answer; it’s rude to do that. You removed a negative sign.

Comment: @Bill But in your method if we increase the range of $n$ from $n=0$ to $1000$ we get the graph goes to zero again. See here: ````Plot[4^(2*n)*n*FractionalPart[Binomial[2*n,n]*E^(2*n)*Log[n]]/ E^(2*n),{n,0,1000},PlotRange->All,WorkingPrecision->256]````

Comment: @Bill Thank you so much for your patience and your comment.

Comment: @Bill Thanks a lot. But the issue I am facing is to simplify the expression inside fractional part.

Comment: @Bill But I think that the limit should exist and the fractional part of $x$ should be in the range $0\leq\{x\}<1$. Computer algebra allows the fractional part to be negative which is not the case in our definition.

Comment: @Bill Thanks! But there is a small typo. In my question inside the fractional part we have $d_{2n}$ instead of $e^{2n}$

Comment: @Thanks again. $d_{n}$ is the LCM of first $n$ natural numbers, so $d_{2n}$ is the LCM of first $2n$ natural numbers

Comment: @Bill At least can we please full simplify $a_n$ as defined by you?

Comment: @Bill Does LCM@@[2n]=LCM[1,2,...,2n]? We need to input LCM[1,2,...,2n]

Comment: @Bill Okay. Thank you so much for your consistent effort. I really appreciate that

Comment: @Max `a[n_]:=N[-Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*2*(HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(j+n)!],{j,0,n}],1920];
f[n_]:=n*4^(2*n)/E^(2*n)* FractionalPart[Binomial[2*n,n]*LCM@@Range[2*n]*a[n]];
t=Table[N[Log[f[n]]],{n,1,800}]
ListPlot[t]` For every extra 100 for n `N[]` needs about 24 more digits precision. If not enough digits there will be Indeterminant shown at the end of `t`, with enough digits this tends to increase forever. If you graph up to `n==100` you can see the small variation which means I haven't found a simple proof that there is no limit. Unless you find errors I think this is done.

Comment: @Bill Thank you! I would really appreciate to have a proof of it. I request you to write as an answer which most humbly I will accept.

Comment: @Max Look at that graph for `n==100` There must be a proof just laying there waiting to be discovered. Either there is a mistake in this and that means there is a limit or there is some simple way to show that it grows without bound. As it is, this isn't satisfying and isn't right. I urge you to go find it.

Comment: @Bill I am requesting you because I am completely new to wolfram cloud. Also I don't have its full version. Please write as an answer. I am really in need.

Comment: It was pointed out earlier that it makes a difference whether $n$ is a real variable (i.e., you use `Limit[]`) or $n$ is a (positive) integer (i.e., you use `DiscreteLimit[]`). Why didn't you clarify that from the beginning instead of wasting people's time? You pestered me for a proof of the first case, but the update to the question shows that is not even the one you're interested in. And if you want a proof, *ask on Math.SE or MathOverflow.* Here questions are about using Mathematica. For your case, one uses `DiscreteLimit[]`. If it can't be made to work, then Mma doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: -1 This question is now completely different from the original version that Daniel Huber answered.

Comment: There is evidence that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a(n) = c 4^n$:
`a[n_] := -2. Sum[
    Binomial[n, j]^2*(HarmonicNumber[n - j] - HarmonicNumber[j])*
     Log[(n + j)!], {j, 0, n}];`
`aTab = a /@ Range[500];`
`rat = Ratios@aTab;`
`nR = N[rat, 64];`
 NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[nR]

(*3.99825*)

It is hard to figure out exactly what $c$ is, (it's not $\frac{a(1)}{4}$). Note also

$\left\{\binom{2n}{n} d_{2n}a_n\right\}$ is the same as $\left\{\binom{2n}{n} d_{2n}\left\{a_n\right\}\right\}$ since $\binom{2n}{n}$ and $d_{2n}$ are always integers.

Comment: The issue with finding a limit for $a(n)$ is that it must be exact as @Bill pointed out, because we need the fractional parts. But looking at $a(n) = c 4^n$ might provide some insight

Answer (score 3):

You are running into problems with machine numbers. You need to calculate with rational numbers and only in the end convert to machine numbers.

The fractional part jumps wildly between -1 and 0. E.g.:

```
Table[FractionalPart[-Binomial[2*n, n]*E^(2*n)*Log[n]] /. 
   n -> (1000 + i)/1000, {i, 10}] // N

{-0.0148151, -0.0297044, -0.0446682, -0.0597069, -0.0748206, \
-0.0900099, -0.105275, -0.120616, -0.136033, -0.151528}
```

The other part of your expression diverges. E.g.:

```
Plot[4^(2*n)*n/E^(2*n), {n, 100, 110}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Therefore, the whole expression jumps wildly between -Infinity and zero.

Comment: ($+1$) Thank you. So is the limit between $-\infty$ and $0$? Also fractional part can be negative? I know that $0\leq \{x\}<1$

Comment: Look in the help, in MMA  fractional part of neg numbers is negative.. If you want a pos. number, take "Abs"

Comment: No, the limit does not exist. If n->Infinity, the value of the expression keeps on jumping all over the place.

Comment: You can extend the Binomial into a continuous function using Gamma. Then the argument of FractionalPart is continuous and decreasing (because of the minus sign) without bond. Therefore the FractionalPart oscillates between -1 and 0 without end.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your comment. But how can the fractional part be negative?

Comment: I think I already answered this. Did you read my answers?

Comment: Yes but I did'nt understand that how the fractional part can be negative. I was taught it is always positive. In MMA is it something else going on?

Comment: Its simply a matter of definition.

Comment: "Please give a proof using mathematica or otherwise that the limit does not exist" -- this is trivial for people who have had calculus. Give it some thought or ask on Math.SE.

Comment: "So I am taking the definition as 0 <= {} < 1 for all  \[Element] ℝ"  Then you must define your own function, e.g., `myFractionalPart[x_] := Sign[x]*FractionalPart[x]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry its not trivial. Please see the question again.

Comment: @Max My apologies if it’s not trivial then I don’t know how to do it

Answer (score 3):

I am going to try to do this one tiny step at a time and explain why each step was done.

First we take the latest combined modifications of the problem and try to see the behavior. Look at a table of the first 16 results.

```
Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}]
  ],{n,1,16}]
```

which returns

```
{(16*(-2+4*Log[2]))/E^2,
 (512*(-89-2*(18*Log[2]-18*Log[24])))/E^4, 
 (12288*(-1922-2*(110*Log[6]+270*Log[24]-270*Log[120]-110*Log[720])))/E^6,
 ...}
```

which gives no intuition about how this behaves. We cannot introduce constants containing decimal points because Mathematica interprets those to be hardware floating point numbers with fixed (small) precision so we use integers at every step.

So CAREFULLY introduce `N`. Because of the use of `FractionalPart` this must be very carefully done, tiny changes that do not change the "value" of the expression can change the digits after the decimal point and thus change the result that `FractionalPart` will return.

```
Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}]]
  ],{n,1,16}]
```

which returns

```
{1.67294,4.28218,10.4978,63.4222,229.579,343.075,316.713,2007.59,
5316.79,7082.07,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}
```

Because of the default number of digits after the decimal point the `FractionalDigits` returns 0. for n>10. So we have to increase the number of digits used in each step to get accurate results. It appears that using 16/10*n or more digits for any n is sufficient.

```
Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],26]
  ],{n,1,16}]
```

which returns

```
{1.6729362167957357592658370,4.28218481304754759884180,
 10.497848815716328549110,63.4222366786640132494,
 229.57858258283231264,343.074869354058602,
 316.7142618116669,2007.609786423297,5330.630523416,5859.6617726,
 43473.132286,85688.9239,92047.81,191913.3,1.4860*^6,3.2*^6}
```

Once we have (hopefully) correctly found the `FractionalPart` we can use another layer of `N` to reduce the number of displayed digits to make this easier to interpret.

```
N[Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],26]
  ],{n,1,16}]]
```

which returns

```
{1.67294,4.28218,10.4978,63.4222,229.579,343.075,316.714,2007.61,
5330.63,5859.66,43473.1,85688.9,92047.8,191913.,1.48599*^6,3.21193*^6}
```

Now because the numbers grow so rapidly I introduce `Log` to make the behavior more understandable.

```
Log[N[Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],26]
  ],{n,1,16}]]]
```

which returns

```
{0.51458,1.45446,2.35117,4.14981,5.43625,5.83795,5.758,7.6047,
 8.58122,8.67585,10.6799,11.3585,11.4301,12.1648,14.2116,14.9824}
```

Now what happens if we explore a larger range of n? To get the correct digits from `FractionalPart we must increase the number of digits.

```
Log[N[Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],160]
  ],{n,1,100}]]]
```

which returns

```
{0.51458,1.45446,2.35117,4.14981,5.43625,5.83795,5.758,7.6047,
8.58122,8.67585,10.6799,11.3585,11.4301,12.1648,14.2116,14.9824,
15.5948,12.4621,17.2348,18.1513,18.427,20.0624,19.3231,20.8685,
19.8536,22.0323,23.8649,24.8205,23.7111,26.0813,25.2607,27.0393,
28.3965,28.014,27.8578,30.1361,31.8927,32.9605,33.1578,34.0535,
35.2177,35.7233,34.8277,32.2319,37.0506,38.6166,40.1351,40.7977,
38.9171,42.2582,42.5116,43.0478,42.1876,43.7382,45.8601,47.2742,
47.8356,41.1281,49.6449,50.4222,50.069,51.7794,52.5686,51.867,
53.3708,53.7243,55.6138,56.3076,56.8647,57.2111,57.1702,58.1792,
60.4195,61.3373,55.0426,62.4402,63.1958,63.8969,65.0679,66.1007,
65.9722,67.2821,67.0065,68.5047,69.2048,69.212,71.3989,71.2431,
71.4204,73.3487,74.7641,73.5054,71.2659,76.786,77.7044,78.1788,
78.8553,79.3371,79.4603,78.2496}
```

If you `ListPlot` that list of numbers you can perhaps better see the behavior.

Notice that the numbers do not consistently increase, for example 5.83795 is followed by 5.758. This has thus far kept me from finding a simple proof that the number grows without bound.

What happens with n up to 400?

```
Log[N[Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],640]],
  {n,300,400}]]]
```

Which returns

```
{236.235,235.558,235.901,235.862,239.181,240.352,240.914,242.617,
242.939,244.305,244.862,244.573,246.435,246.684,248.292,248.787,
247.488,250.648,250.835,252.005,250.908,253.197,254.343,254.69,
256.026,255.877,257.477,257.519,259.167,259.263,257.293,260.635,
261.416,260.158,262.779,264.557,263.453,264.87,266.739,266.975,
265.683,268.427,269.824,270.681,271.112,271.893,272.703,273.8,
273.693,274.969,274.759,276.846,277.436,276.488,278.789,279.31,
280.545,280.829,281.479,281.909,283.081,282.897,284.071,283.718,
286.087,287.35,288.584,287.609,288.722,289.406,291.171,291.816,
292.674,292.548,294.792,295.23,295.951,295.833,297.272,298.468,
299.361,298.744,299.562,299.997,301.944,303.375,303.122,304.766,
305.205,306.414,306.328,306.326,308.396,309.484,308.861,309.445,
311.599,311.277,313.303,313.015,312.439}
```

As n grows larger the number of digits grows larger the calculation takes longer and longer to complete.

And

```
Log[N[Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],1600]],
  {n,980,1000}]]]]
```

returns

```
{761.945,764.5,764.616,765.581,764.12,766.065,766.151,768.168,
768.928,770.478,771.257,770.088,772.856,773.325,774.574,775.311,
775.214,776.627,777.704,778.647,779.35}
```

And

```
N[Log[N[Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],3200]], 
  {n,2000,2000}]]]]
```

returns

```
{1552.33}
```

And

```
N[Log[N[Table[
  n*(4/E)^(2*n)*
  FractionalPart[N[-2*Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*Apply[LCM,Range[2*n]]*
  (HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])*Log[(n+j)!],{j,0,n}],6400]], 
  {n,4000,4000}]]]]
```

returns

```
  {3098.21}
```

Here is a `ListPlot` of n versus `Log` of your expression for some n from 1 to 4096

[image]

All this is not a proof that the expression does not have a limit, but it seems to be a strong hint that this is true. You need to think about what assumptions you might be making and what I might be making. For example, I have assumed that `n` is a discrete integer, since you used `n` as an index for your `Sum`. But I might imagine that there are other assumptions that neither of us have critically examined.

And I ALWAYS assume first that I've made undiscovered mistakes.

A question I'm asking myself. Why isn't there MORE variation introduced by the `FractionalPart`? The `Log` may be making this less obvious, but the points just look too much like a straight line. I expect to see more variation than this. In earlier versions of this, when `Plot` wasn't assuming that `n` was an integer, I think I remember seeing more variation in the value of the expression. Perhaps it was those non-integer values for `n` that were introducing more variation.

Approximate the behavior of a[n] up to n=4096.

```
a[n_]:=-Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*2(HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])Log[(j+n)!],{j,0,n}];
nlist=Union[Table[Floor[(4096^(1/60))^j],{j,0,60}]];
logapoints=Map[{#,Log[a[#]]}&,nlist];
logaline=Fit[logapoints,{1,n},n]
Show[ListPlot[logapoints],Plot[logaline,{n,1,4096}]]
(*E^-1.11282==0.328631,E^1.38579==3.99798 so a[n] is approximately 1/3*4^n*)
```

Now as a separate step approximate the behavior of expr[n]. These number get even bigger and take longer, so I only go up to n=2048.

```
a[n_]:=-Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*2(HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])Log[(j+n)!],{j,0,n}];
nlist=Union[Table[Floor[(2048^(1/30))^j],{j,0,30}]];
d[n_]:=Apply[LCM,Range[n]];
$MaxExtraPrecision=4400;
expr[n_]:=n(4/E)^(2n)N[FractionalPart[Binomial[2n,n]d[2n]a[n]],Ceiling[16/10n]]
logexprpoints=Map[{#,N[Log[expr[#]]]}&,nlist];
logexprline=Fit[logexprpoints,{1,n},n]
Show[ListPlot[logexprpoints,PlotRange->All],Plot[logexprline,{n,1,2048}]]
(*E^2.01589==7.50741,E^0.776001==2.17277 so expr[n] is approximately 7.5*2.17277^n*)
```

Display those plots. Look carefully at them. Perhaps display the tables of the numbers and look at the relative difference between a[n] and my approximation without using Log. Repeat that for expr[n]. See whether the relative error is small and is not increasing as n grows. Hopefully you will either uncover an error of mine or perhaps of yours or that this will give you some confidence that expr[n] grows exponentially as n grows.

Let's look at the relative error without using `Log` which can sometimes hide the magnitude of the errors involved.

```
a[n_]:=-Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*2(HarmonicNumber[n-j]-HarmonicNumber[j])Log[(j+n)!],{j,0,n}];
nlist=Union[Table[Floor[(4096^(1/60))^j],{j,0,60}]];
arelativeerror=N[N[Map[a[#]/(1/3*4^#)&,nlist],120]]
ListPlot[arelativeerror]
```

and

```
a[n_]:=-Sum[Binomial[n,j]^2*2(HarmonicNumber[n-j]- HarmonicNumber[j])Log[(j+n)!],{j,0,n}];
nlist=Union[Table[Floor[(2048^(1/30))^j],{j,0,30}]];
d[n_]:=Apply[LCM,Range[n]];
$MaxExtraPrecision=4400;
expr[n_]:=n(4/E)^(2n)N[FractionalPart[Binomial[2n,n]d[2n]a[n]], Ceiling[16/10n]]
exprrelativeerror=N[Map[expr[#]/(7.5*2.17277^#)&,nlist]]
ListPlot[exprrelativeerror]
```

Those errors are larger and don't tend towards zero as n increases I wish they were better. But they seem to show that the error is less than one digit when some of the numbers are thousands! of digits. So a simple log linear approximation maybe isn't too awful. I suspect a much more precise model might be far more complicated and difficult to interpret. If you can come up with a better approximate model that is even closer to the exact data and the relative error does tend to zero as n grows then I would love to see it.

Unless you can find some flaw in this or suggest some specific experiment to do to try to expose the behavior of this... I think, I hope, we are done with this one.

PLEASE check every character of this to try to find and correct any of my mistakes.

Comment: $(+1)$. Thank you so much for this elegant answer. So can we conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\ 4^{2n}}{e^{2n}}\ \left\{\binom{2n}{n} d_{2n}a_n\right\}\leq \frac{3}{4}$$ where $$a_n:= -\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj^2(2(H_{n-j}-H_j)\log((j+n)!) $$?

Comment: Thank you. But for calculating the values I need a closed form for $a_n$. Can you please help me to simplify $a_n$ using Wolfram cloud or otherwise?

Comment: @Max I added two blocks of code and a bit of explanation at the end. Perhaps this will help enough that you can find mistakes or that you will think this is done.